# Jquery multiple columns selector based on class

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with multiple rows and tds. Of the table I would like to select two td's of different rows having classes 
invalid-case-sensitive-value, invalid-sentence-scope-value

Is it possible to achieve those in single statement using `find()` or any other function.

Something like:

```
var errorRows = $("topic-table").find("td.invalid-case-sensitive-value", "td.invalid-sentence-scope-value");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the mulitple selector: [link](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Docu:

> Description: Selects the combined results of all the specified
>   selectors.
>
> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. An alternative to this combinator is the .add()
>   method.

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  div,span,p {
    width: 126px;
    height: 60px;
    float:left;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-size:14px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>div</div>

  <p class="myClass">p class="myClass"</p>
  <p class="notMyClass">p class="notMyClass"</p>
  <span>span</span>
<script>$("div,span,p.myClass").css("border","3px solid red");</script>

</body>
</html>
```